# Nodejs write file progress bar in html

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to generate a file in nodejs and I want to show writing file progress bar in the client-side HTML page. because I am writing a 5 lakh data into a file. once files generates complete in nodejs, it should notify users on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical design pattern for communicating server-side progress back to the client is to have the client establish a webSocket (or socket.io) connection to the server and then the server can send regular progress updates over the socket.  When the client receives the updates and when it receives the final notification indicating completion, it can use Javascript to update the visual progress in the web page or do anything else it wants to in the page.

I would recommend using the socket.io library on both client and server as it makes things simpler than a plain webSocket.

Comment: Far easier in this case to use EventSource.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource  Have the client request an event stream for a particular job ID or something.